# Railway Booking Engine: There are 67 seats in a train, with 5 seats per row and 2 seats in the last row

Tags: python, list

I am designing a program in python.
i am having 67 seats in train and i need to devide seats into rows per row can have 5 seat and last row will have 2 seats .
I do not know how i will design this.
I am pasting code what i have designed .

```
class Reservation(object):

    def __init__(self, seats, perrow, lastrow):
        self.seats = seats
        self.perrow = perrow
        self.lastrow = lastrow
        self.allseats = []
        import math
        from decimal import Decimal
        rows = math.ceil((Decimal(seats)/Decimal(perrow)))
        for i in range(int(rows)):
            self.allseats.append([])
        iii = 0
        iiii = 1
        for ii in range(int(rows)):
            for b in range(perrow):
                self.allseats[iii].append({'SEATNO'+str(iiii): 'Free'})
                iiii = iiii +1
            iii = iii + 1
        for i in range(perrow-lastrow):
            self.allseats[-1].pop()
        print self.allseats
```

Above code is working fine but that is not efficient one . If there is any efficient way please let me know that will be helpful to me

Comment: What is the expected output of this code?

Comment: Mixing up `Decimal` and `math` (which works on `float` values) is generally a bad idea, especially when you ultimately just want integers. I suspect you just don't know about floor division (`//`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def make_seats(seats, perrow, lastrow):
    full_rows = seats // perrow
    return [['Free' for _ in range(perrow)]
            for _ in range(full_rows)] + [['Free' for _ in range(lastrow)]]
```

You don't really need the `lastrow` argument, because it has to be `seats % perrow`, but since it's part of your input, I used it.

Anyway, to understand what this means, let's break it down.

First, the number of full rows is just the number of rows it takes to fit all the seats, rounded down.

Now, each full row is `['Free' for _ in range(perrow)]`—that is, `perrow` copies of the string `'Free'`.

And we have `full_rows` full rows, hence the nested list comprehension.

And then we have to tack on one more row with `lastrow` seats.